# How to get parent category id while creating new category in magento?

Tags: magento

I am just working on Magento custom extension that is when I create new category belonging to specific category let say "Accessories". Then I want it to display this functionality otherwise I don't want to it to be visible. There is no problem in edit category in edit I can get parent category via `Mage::registry('current_category')->getParentCategory()->getId();` but can not get parent id while creating new category.

Kindly give me the best solution guys.

Comment: Do you want to get the parent category id from products?

Comment: no i want to get parent category id when creating new sub category (Manage Categories->Add Subcategory)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
<?php
      $_categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
                ->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->addAttributeToFilter('level',3);
   // $_categories = $_helper->getStoreCategories();
        if (count($_categories) > 0){
            foreach($_categories as $_category){
                $parentId=Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId())->getParentId();
                echo $parentId;
            }
        }
?>
```

You may change the level as you need.